# Reinicio en ciclo for

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for, bucles

Estoy haciendo un programa el cual lee un archivo (el cual contiene en lineas palabras; está adjunto) y tiene que regresar un archivo nuevo con la palabra en cuestión y la suma de sus caracteres (estos los generé a partir de un diccionario).
El problema está en que realiza todo pero acumula la sumas, es decir, a partir del valor de la palabra anterior, suma el nuevo valor en lugar de cero. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar a solucionar este problema?

IMAGEN DEL ARCHIVO DE TEXTO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CÓDIGO:

```
def glich(pal):
    global c
    valores={}
    for i in range (27):
        abc = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        valores[abc[i]] = i


    palabra = pal.upper()
    #c = 0
    for letra in palabra:
        a = valores[letra]
        c = c+a
    return c


c=0


arch=open("palabras.txt","r")

val=[]
palas=[]
for linea in arch:
    glich(linea.rstrip("\n"))
    palas.append(linea.rstrip("\n"))
    val.append(c)
arch.close()


nuevo=open("suma.txt","w")

for i in range(len(palas)):
    nuevo.write(palas[i]+","+str(val[i])+"\n")
```

COMO DEBE DE SALIR:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

COMO SALE:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código está mal indentado, debido a la forma en que lo has pegado, por lo que no está claro cómo debería ser. Mira http://bit.ly/SOesPASTE para pegarlo correctamente. Me da la impresión de que sobra la variable global `c`.

Comment: Listo :) Muchas gracias por el comentario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo de estas forma:

```
# imports 
# pprint es para una impresion de arreglos mas legible y string para el alfabeto
from pprint import pprint
import string

#con libreria string
#str = string.ascii_lowercase

#sin libreria string
str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
# abrimos el documento
with open("palabras.txt","r") as f:
    # hacemos un loop de las palabras en el archivo y luego otro loop de las letras en la palabra con el
    # index() no das la posicion de la letra en el string de letras minusculas a eso le sumamos 1 y lo vamos sumando 
    val = [ ( x.rstrip('\r\n' ),sum( (str.index(i)+1) for i in x if i.rstrip('\r\n') )  ) for x in f.readlines() if x.strip() ]
pprint(val)
```

resultado:

```
[('flojo', 58), ('excelente', 93), ('conocimiento', 135), ('trabajo', 67)]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la sugerencia pero me gustaría hacerlo sin importar librerías. ¿Hay alguna forma?

Comment: pprint no es necesaria y string puedes cambiarlos por string ="abcdefghij" etc..

Comment: Genial ! Muchas gracias :)